# Как менять текст в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Питаюсь в RichTextBox изменить текст ничего не получается.
В гугле что то ничего не нашел как это решить.

Делать пробую так:

```
private void saveSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    myBox.Text += "dfdsfds";

}
```

Или возможно есть другой?
Пробовал использовать другой вариант  TextBox но там нет возможности при вводе текст переходить на новую строку :(

Comment: Зачем вам `RichTextBox`, если вы не используете его главную фишку, форматирование? Сделайте публичное свойство, например `public string Text {get;set;} = "Привет мир!";`, задайте окну `DataContext` на класс, который содержит это свойство, в XAML используйте `TextBox` с привязкой к свойству (`<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>`), готово, у вас поле для ввода, да еще и данные в одном месте, а UI в другом, как и положено в грамотном WPF проекте.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.

```
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(myBox.Document.ContentStart, myBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        textRange.Text = "Another world, another text!";
```